# Pequeno bug com botões dentro da nav tabs no bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estou tendo um problema com bootstrap `nav tabs`. Seguinte: estou construindo uma tela com 4 `tabs`, sendo que cada `tab` possui botões para várias ações. Quando clico em algum botão da primeira, ou segunda, ou terceira `tab`, ele sempre vai pra última, e sai da `tab` principal onde estou clicando. Vou mandar imagens com o requerido problema

Essa é uma das tabs, irei clicar na aba `1. Abertas`:

[image]

Nessa segunda imagem, eu já tinha clicado na primeira aba em um botão qualquer e automaticamente se referenciou a última aba, isso acontece em qualquer aba que eu clicar, como eu já tinha falado, clico em botões da primeira, clico em botões da segunda, e também dos da terceira, e vai pra última aba.

[image]

Comment: Coloca seu código pra vermos onde você pode estar errando.

Comment: O código tá nesse link do jsfiddle  -- https://jsfiddle.net/mqexj4hs/

Comment: O código não funciona, tentei arrumar mas está bem estranho.